# Necessity of assigning IDs to views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I am new to Android development and have been investigating the activity/fragment lifecycle RE recreating views.

I have read in the documentation/tutorials that views in an activity/fragment will be recreated automatically if they have an id (can't find a link to this).

My question is, do views that are created programmatically require an id, even if we do not require the id for other purposes?

It is simple enough to use `View.generateViewId()` to assign Ids, but it would be nice if this was not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, do views that are created programmatically require an id, even if we do not require the id for other purposes?

Short answer: No, they don't *require* an ID. The long answer is of course that it depends on what you're doing and what state you need to save.

This article actually covers the topic pretty thoroughly, so I'd recommend reading it if you haven't: http://www.charlesharley.com/2012/programming/views-saving-instance-state-in-android/

Comment: Hmm, interesting link. I've figured out that there are 2 cases where the recreation occurs: rotating the screen, and "if the system destroys the activity due to system constraints (rather than normal app behavior), then although the actual Activity instance is gone, the system remembers that it existed such that if the user navigates back to it, the system creates a new instance of the activity using a set of saved data that describes the state of the activity when it was destroyed".

I guess this indicates that if stateful views don't have ids, they will be restored to an incorrect state.